# PLSQL Variable Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql

I send a parameter in my PLSQL function which is the name of the Table. 
In my code, I want to insert into the table that is being received in the parameter.

When I type the insert statement

```
insert into TABLE_VARIABLE_NAME 
VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

It gives the error of Table Doesn't exist. 
How can I use Table's Name as the parameter of the function?

Comment: can elaborate it more for better answer with some example of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full demo code you can try it and even the above hint is absolutely correct ,i just elaborated it more with insert values as varchar2  :-

```
create table td (valued varchar2(10));

create or replace procedure dhar_conn(tname varchar2)
 as
 begin
    execute immediate 'insert into '||tname||' values(''1'')';
 commit;
 end;/

 execute dhar_conn('td')
```

Comment: is there any sql injection risk?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need dynamic SQL with execute immediate.

```
execute immediate 'insert into ' || l_var_name || 'values (1,2,3)'
```

Comment: its correct and will work fine down you can see the full demo with values as varchar2